How to routing view in a child of view routed?
I have a website use Vue Nuxt Typescript Pinia Tailwind.
I don't know how to load a view that view is loaded by route of top navigation cuz inside loaded view I have sidebar menu, I want each choice on this will add route (its maybe that I want to do like this) to load another view inside of this loaded page.
This is my image describe my think
if it's able, I want add route and routing to load view inside and stay on this page.

You can add another <router-view /> on your Profile page and nest subpages. Have a look at the User.vue component in the documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html
